# SSH and git pull returns cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD in Github Actions

Tags: ssh, github-actions, cicd

I am trying to create a basic deployment pipeline for a legacy codebase that the team have been deploying manually via ssh + git pull. What am I missing? It looks like the user that is running the git commands in the pipeline does not have permissions to read the repository, but I am not sure if this is the case or how to fix it.

My deploy job looks like this:

```
staging:
    name: Deploy to staging
    needs: build-and-test-staging
    permissions:
      contents: write
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    environment:
      name: staging
      url: https://staging.com

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: alpine:3.19.1
      options: --user 1001
    steps:
      - name: SSH into server
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v1.0.3
        with:
          host: ${{ vars.REMOTE_HOST_NAME }}
          username: ${{ vars.USER_NAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          proxy_host: ${{ vars.BASTION_HOST_NAME }}
          proxy_username: ${{ vars.USER_NAME }}
          proxy_key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          script_stop: true
          timeout: 60s
          proxy_timeout: 60s
          script: | 
            sudo su
            sudo -u username bash
            cd /home/username/domains/staging.com/public_html
            git config --global --add safe.directory "$PWD"
            git branch
            git pull
            npm ci && ng build --c=staging
            echo "Deployment job completed"
```

Error:

```
======CMD======
sudo su
sudo -u username bash
cd /home/username/domains/staging.com/public_html
git config --global --add safe.directory "$PWD"
git branch
git pull
npm ci && ng build --c=staging
echo "Deployment job completed"
======END======
out:   master
out: * staging
err: error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
2024/03/18 14:07:59 Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: adding sudo -u username to git and npm command did the trcik